# createjs Y position inside of movieclip

Tags: createjs

I have a graphic in an animation playing within a movieclip
What I want to do is get the x and y position of the graphic inside of that movieclip as it animates.

but I'm finding that the x an y don't update, even though at the moment, I'm checking within the tick function, I'm using globalToLocal

```
function tickHandler(event) {
//get the x and y of this mc using globalToLocal 
console.log(exportRoot.game_anim.meterMC.awd.globalToLocal(exportRoot.game_anim.meterMC.awd.x, exportRoot.game_anim.meterMC.awd.y))

stage.update();
}

exportRoot.gotoAndStop("game")
exportRoot.game_anim.meterMC.arrowYou.addEventListener("mousedown",function (evt) {
var _this = evt.target

 var mouseRight = 0;
 var mouseLeft = 180;

 var offset = {x: _this.x - evt.stageX, y: _this.y - evt.stageY};

 evt.addEventListener("mousemove" , function(ev){
// )

 var pt = exportRoot.game_anim.meterMC.globalToLocal(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY)


 if ( pt.y > mouseLeft){
    percent = 100;
} else if (pt.y < mouseRight){
    percent = 0;
} else {

    percent = Math.round(((pt.y - mouseRight) / (mouseLeft - mouseRight)*100));
_this.y = pt.y; 
}
 if ( pt.y > mouseLeft){ 

}

;

})

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `localToGlobal` with a static point in your target clip. For example:

`var pt = myMC.subMC.localToGlobal(0,0);
console.log(pt.x, pt.y);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll give it a try